# Get JSON of instagram post

Tags: php, curl, instagram-api

I'm trying to get json of instagram post. The url to fetch data:

```
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/" . $_GET['media'] . "/?__a=1";
```

When I'm get this **url in browser - all fine**, json returned. Btw browser not logged in to instagram. But when I use curl or `file_get_contents($url);` it return http code 302 with header 'location' to login page.

Code sample:

```
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/" . $_GET['media'] . "/?__a=1";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json') );
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($data);
```

Maybe curl options should be modified to look like browser.

### Update

I have try same headers as in browser, include cookie, but no luck, seems this impossible. I have already written page using this hack, what stop working recently. Using API means rewrite everything as data in response is different.

Comment: You should use the [instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) instead. They have developed that specifically for developers to be able to interact with their service. The way you're doing it is hacky (and could even be a breach of their Terms of Service). Any changes to their UI/URL's and your code could break while the API will be the same.

Comment: you're better off using their API instead instead of hacking your way to it

Comment: @MagnusEriksson This is only a problem as of yesterday. It was working previously. Unfortunately I need a solution without using the API as well so I'm very interested in a solution!

Comment: _"This is only a problem as of yesterday. It was working previously."_ - That's exactly the reason why you should use the API. The site can change at any moment without any warning, which means that you continuously will need to "fix" your code. It most likely goes against their Terms of Service as well.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this is quite simple, you're trying to access a web-resource that's protected by authentication (this should be obvious) or protected by detecting non-standard behavior. The reason for your curl request failing is because it's missing a [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) header or some form of other header needed to identify you as a human. Usually it's the cookie identifying you and your authenticated session as trusted with the server. At some point, you've most likely logged in with your browser and that's why the request works in your browser - but not the curl/php logic or you're missing headers such as `User-Agent` that masks the use of curl.

[image]
Here's an example of a cookie string identifying me as myself. Without it, I wouldn't be able to do these requests in my browser. There for, as long as the server sends `Set-Cookie: ...` the browser honors it and saves it, keeps track of it and sends it with every request.

Either you borrow a cookie from your browser session and implement it temporarily into your curl requests, or you implement the login logic before sending curl requests. But you should do the right thing and start using the [Instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) as pointed out by Magnus Eriksson in the comments.

The later is the recommended, and there are some libraries altho they are old. But perhaps they will give you an idea of how to go about it.

### [Instagram-PHP-API](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API) library as an example.

```php
use MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram;

$instagram = new Instagram(array(
    'apiKey'      => 'YOUR_APP_KEY',
    'apiSecret'   => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
    'apiCallback' => 'YOUR_APP_CALLBACK'
));

echo "<a href='{$instagram->getLoginUrl()}'>Login with Instagram</a>";
```

And if you're left wondering, "what the hell is an API", [here's (Tom Scott - This Video Has X Views)](https://youtu.be/BxV14h0kFs0) a video to a good explanation and why it's not a good idea to pretend to be a human - but instead use API's.

Comment: +1 Thanks for explaining. But I mention I'm not logged in, and using api not answers the question as page have to be rewriten in this case.

Comment: Then it's probably because they've identified that you're not using a browser (if you copy all the headers shown in your browser, i'm 99.9% sure that the request will work in curl as well). I'd still say, use the API or a "proper" [scrape](https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-php-scraper) library which has gone through all the pit falls you're going through.

Comment: @Torxed for reference, this was not an issue as of 2 days ago. It is something new. I am also not able to get it working and I need a solution that is not using the API so I'd be very interested in a code example if you got something working!

Comment: @WilliamHampshire If that's the case I'm sure they've introduced some form of human verification to make scraping harder. And if that's the case, it's even more a reason to use the API as that's the way they intended it to be used :) I could be wrong tho, but the API should "always" work.

Comment: Instagram Legacy API will be disabled at June 29, 2020. Other APIs will work with token what can be received after app review, it takes up to week or longer to receive token.

Comment: @LeonidMew - In the end, it will take you way longer to keep fixing your code to address changes to their site. Your code will also be broken every time it happens, until you've fixed it each time. You have now gotten the same advice from many people. Use their API. Why are you so against that? That is the best solution to your problem.

Comment: @LeonidMew - Also, just because something _can_ take "up to a week", it doesn't mean it will. They tend to be pretty quick.